# How to change login link URL in shopify checkout

Tags: web, single-sign-on, shopify

I have implemented an SSO service into shopify using multipass but i just finally need to edit the checkout so when someone clicks the little blue login button they are taken to my authentication url.

I am on shopify plus and can access the checkout.liquid file but no idea on how to actually just change the url within the login button.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it using javascript since the login button is located in the `content_for_layout` tag and you don't have direct access to it.

Another approach will be to use the liquid split filter on the above tag but that will be a little tricky and more work.

Just use plain javascript is my call.

Comment: Yeah thats what i did, the login link in checkout takes you to /login so i just put a redirect in the head on /account/login and works a treat

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the login link on checkout using JavaScript if using Shopify Plus.

Add the following snippet inside script tags on your custom `checkout.liquid` template.

```
Checkout.$(document).on('page:load', function() {
   Checkout.$('a[href*="account/login"]').attr("href", "YOUR_URL");
});
```